# How to abstract a line of code into a variable

Tags: java

I want to run a line of a code in another method. Specifically, I would like to take a line of code **x** and run it in a new thread.

Here is my pseudo-code

```
LineOfCode line;
...
new NewThread(line).run()
```

Here is pseudo-code for `NewThread` class

```
public class NewThread {

    LineOfCode line;

    NewThread(LineOfCode line){
        this.line = line;
    }

    public void run(){

        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                line.execute();
            }
        };

        thread.start();
    }
}
```

How do I abstract a line of code into a variable?

Probably a stupid question, but can't think of obvious solution.

Comment: That's what the `Runnable` interface is for...

Comment: What do you mean "line of code"? What if that line depends on external variables?

Comment: @cricket_007 an SQL query for example

Comment: That's completely different than what you are asking, then... You had this tagged with android, so you want a SQLiteOpenHelper

Comment: @the_prole You need to explain what you want to do with a _concrete_ example.  I suspect this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info), as executing a SQL query is completely different from executing an arbitrary line of Java code.  If the line of code is Java and is not known until runtime that's a completely _different_ problem.  Until you provide a concrete example we really cannot answer the question.

Comment: @cricket_007 You're right, this is a pure Java question... however, Andy answered my question. I can create a `Runnable` and call `.run()` wherever I want to run it. .

Comment: Only if you know the line of Java you want to execute at compile time.

Comment: Clear question with clear answer. I don't understand down-votes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java 8+, you would be able to use a [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html):

```
Runnable line = () -> { System.out.println("I am doing something"); };
```

(Thanks to JoopEggen for providing this in a comment).

In prior versions, you'd need to create a `Runnable` explicitly:

```
Runnable line = new Runnable() {
  @Override public void run() {
    System.out.println("I am doing something");
  }
};
```

You can pass this to your `MyThread`, and just call the `run()` method.

Actually, you don't need `MyThread` at all: you can simply do:

```
new Thread(line).start();
```

and it runs the Runnable: this is the preferred way of creating new Threads (rather than subclassing directly).

Comment: Clear question with clear answer. I don't understand down-votes.